# Find the image of $|z-1|=1$ under the mapping $f(z)=z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the image of $|z-1|=1$ under the mapping $f(z)=z^2.$ I know that this is a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(1,0),$ given by $r=2\cos\theta.$ So I have $$z=2\cos\theta e^{i \theta}$$ and so $$f(z)=4\cos^2\theta e^{i 2 \theta.}$$

Is this correct and how do I interpret this geometrically?

Comment: Why is $r= 2 cos \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. Geometrically, the image is a [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid):
$t\to (1+e^{it})^2$ with $t\in [0,2\pi)$.

P.S. Note that your expression $4\cos^2\theta e^{i 2 \theta.}$ implies that in polar coordinates we have $\rho(2\theta)=2(1+\cos(2\theta))$.

Comment: How can this be seen from my expression for $f(z)$?

Comment: @user374859 May be you can try to write it in polar coordinates,

Comment: @user374859 See my P.S. in my edited answer.

Comment: Could you explain how you got that expression please?

Comment: @user374859 Use $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$.